# Ping continuously on static IP and if return false send Email

Tags: c#, ip-address, ping

I am stuck in a confusion so knocking the community door . 
I need to make a program through which i need to hit the particular `static IP` address continuously(Business need) . and if any time the particular IP address doesn't reply I need to send emergency  Email to higher authorities that server is down its .

I need to ask some questions which one is suitable for this things ?

- Can console application is able to get my job done?
- how can i make my console application running and hitting all the
  time?
- What should be the approach should i use loop for continuous hit

I tried with the for loop but I am getting some sort of problem , When i run the code below some time it is `returning false like after every 25 requests` that `return false 1 time` , what is the problem ?

```
public static bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
    {
        bool pingable = false;
        Ping pinger = null;

        try
        {
            pinger = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
            pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch (PingException)
        {
           // send email something went wrong please check 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pinger != null)
            {
                pinger.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return pingable;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count; ;
        string address = "ip-adress";
        for(count = 1; count >0; count++ )
        {
            bool response = PingHost(address);
            if (response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping successfull  " + address);
            }
            else
            {
              // send email that server is down. 
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: `returning false like after every 25 requests` probably something environmental, it would be unlikely there is a bug in ping

Comment: There are many free services that already do this; just wondering why you're reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @CaiusJard i would appreciate if you can send me some links for the same

Comment: You shouldn't take 1 failure as a failure of the service, or else you'll get false positives. Ping is UDP, so losses are possible (e.g. never reaches server, or never comes back to you).

Comment: @John what about my other concerns ? can you please clear me those points

Comment: You could write a windows service in a loop. I'm with @Caius though. You should probably use an existing service for uptime monitoring.

Comment: @John could you please mention the name of those services

Comment: A quick Google search reveals Uptime Robot.

Comment: I would do a scheduled task or a windows service. Also I would use a timer instead of a loop.

Comment: Just because `A` cannot ping `B`, that does *not* imply that `B` is down and not actively servicing requests. And in the opposite direction, just because you *can* ping `B` doesn't imply that `B` is necessarily *able to perform its actual job*, unless its entire job is just to respond to ping requests (unlikely). The only way to know if `B` is *doing its job* is to actually monitor those requests for work and tracking success/failure (server)/failure (network), etc.